# Saving state of UISwitch of cells in UITableView to pass data to source controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch, pass-data

I have a `ListTableView` with cells organized in several sections.
Another `FilterTableView` (filter settings for the `ListTableView`) provided by another controller. Every cell of `FilterTableView` has a `UISwitch` to set the showing/hiding state of a specified section of `ListTableView`.

How exactly do I save the `BOOL` state of `UISwitch`?

What kind of model do I need to provide?

What is the right way to pass the state of `UISwitch` of cells of 
`FilterTableView` to show/hide sections in `ListTableView`?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you have any code of any attempts you have made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a stroyboard you can create an unwind segue (to go back from FilterTableViewCtrl to ListTableViewCtrl). This case you can save data in the unwind action method which is located in ListTableViewCtrl.

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue*)unwindSegue
{
    UIViewController* sourceViewController = unwindSegue.sourceViewController;
    if ([sourceViewController isKindOfClass:[FilterTableViewCtrl class]])
    {
        FilterTableViewCtrl* filter = (FilterTableViewCtrl*)unwindSegue.sourceViewController;
        //read state of filter, and update list (self)
    }
}
```

More details in: View Controller Programming Guide for iOS / Creating an Unwind Segue

Answer (score 0):

You need to either pass a reference to the item in your data source to the cell so it can change it directly (for example, pass in a `Filter` object), or you need to make the `FilterTableView` a delegate of each cell and have the cell notify its delegate when the switch value changes.

If the cell is generic and you also use it in other places for other things, go with the delegate pattern. But if it's unique to this table view, it's probably easier just to pass it the `Filter` object. That way it can also set its label and switch state itself, rather than requiring the data source to set its values.